# QML/ C++: ReferenceError: model is not defined when passing model from C++ to QML

Tags: c++, qml

I am creating a subclass of `QAbstractListModel` called `MyModel`, these are the role names:

```
QHash<int, QByteArray> MyModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> names;
    names[FILE] = "file";
    return names;
}
```

This class contains a vector of elements that I populate in main:

```
qmlRegisterType<MyModel>("MyModels", 1, 0, "MyModel");

MyModel my_model;
my_model.loadData();

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

engine.setImportPathList( QStringList() << "qrc:///" );
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("cpp_my_model"), &my_model);
engine.load( QUrl( "qrc:/Resources/Qml/main.qml" ) )
```

In `main.qml`, I added this `GridView` to show the items of my model:

```
GridView
{
    id: my_view
    objectName: "my_view"

    cellWidth: my_view.width / 5
    cellHeight: my_view.cellWidth

    anchors
    {
        left: parent.left;
        right: parent.right;
        top: title_bar.bottom
        bottom: parent.bottom;
    }

    model: cpp_my_model

    delegate: MyItem
    {
        file: model.file
    }
}
```

In `MyItem.qml`:

```
Item {
    id: my_item
    objectName: "my_item"

    required property string file

    Image
    {
        source: "file:///" + file
    }
}
```

When I do this, I get the error as many times as there are items in the model:
**ReferenceError: model is not defined**

However, when I create the component in `main.qml`:

```
    Component
    {
        id: my_component

        Item {
            id: my_item
            objectName: "my_item"

            Image
            {
                width: my_view.cellWidth
                height: my_view.cellHeight
                source: "file:///" + model.file
            }
        }
    }

    delegate: my_component
```

Doing this, it works and I don't understand why. Note: I am very new to QML and I might be missing something silly.

EDIT:
It seems that if I leave MyItem instantiation empty it works:

```
delegate: MyItem {}
```

instead of:

```
delegate: MyItem
{
    file: model.file
}
```

QML seems to magically assigns model.file to MyItem.file. Still, if there is a reference or someone that can explain how all this works it will save me many confusing days ahead.

Comment: Is there a typo in your code? You have this line: `name: model.name`, but I don't see a property called `name` in your model.

Comment: @JarMan, yes, it's a typo, I edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: `MyItem` also doesn't seem to have a property called `name` either. Should that be `file: model.file`?

Comment: Yes, it's a simplified version of the code and I forgot to change that, sorry!

Comment: I'm going to guess that your issue might have something to do with your property name (`file`) being identical to the model's role. Does it work if you use a different name?

Comment: I added an answer for what solved it for me. What you said is true,  the name of the role being identical to the property is what caused the issue.
If I change either one, or just avoid `file: model.file` altogether it works.